# Implementation of Curried Functions in Scheme

Tags: programming-languages, scheme, racket, currying

What happens when I do the following?

```
(define ((func x) y)
    (if (zero? y)
        ((func x) 1)
        12))
```

I understand that I can do this:

```
(define curried (func 5))
```

And now I can use curried. What I'm curious about is in the definition of the function. Does the line

```
((func x) 1)
```

create a new lambda with x as the argument, and then invoke it on 1? Or is it smarter than that and it just re-uses the existing one. (For example, if I do `(curried 0)`, the `((func x) 1)` line would be equivalent to `(curried 1)` - does PLAI Scheme do this?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Scheme standard it is specified that

```
(define (f x) 42) is short for (define f (lambda (x) 42)) .
```

The natural (non-standard) generalization implies:

```
(define ((f x) y) (list x y)) is short for (define (f x) (lambda (y) (list x y)))
                which is short for (define f (lambda (x) (lambda (y) (list x y))))
```

To test it, let's try the example in DrScheme

Welcome to DrScheme, version 4.1.3.3-svn5dec2008 [3m].
Language: Module; memory limit: 384 megabytes.

> (define ((f x) y) (list x y))
>   (f 1)
>
> ((f 1) 2)
>   (1 2)

If we name the temporary value, it might be easier to see what happens:

> (define h (f 1))
>   (h 2)
>   (1 2)
>   (h 3)
>   (1 3)

Since "PLAI Scheme" is implemented in DrScheme, I believe it inherits this shortcut notation.

Comment: gotcha. to answer my question now - this expansion will happen even in  the function 'f', right?

Comment: Which f are talking about now?

Answer (score 2):

It's been too long since I worked with scheme, but you might find [this article](http://www.engr.uconn.edu/~jeffm/Papers/curry.html) helpful.
It describes the implementation of two macros, c-lambda and c-define which allow implicit curried definitions of lambda expressions.

Comment: hmm, an interesting article, but this behavior i'm asking about is built-in to plai scheme, and i want to know how it is implemented - the article implements a different version of currying.

Answer (score 0):

soegaard's answer is correct - this is the traditional expansion. However, drscheme is smart!

The following code I've found to be equivalent in running time:

Original source:

```
(define ((substitute lv value) e)
  (cond [(LogicVar? e)
     (type-case LogicVar e
       [lv-any (id) (if (symbol=? id (lv-any-id lv))
                value
                e)]
       [lv-cons (f r) 
            (lv-cons ((substitute lv value) f)
                 ((substitute lv value) r))])]
    [(cons? e)
     (cons ((substitute lv value) (car e))
           ((substitute lv value) (cdr e)))]
    [else e]))
```

Attempt at optimization:

```
(define (substitute lv value)
  (local ([define inner
        (lambda (e)
          (cond [(LogicVar? e)
             (type-case LogicVar e
               [lv-any (id) (if (symbol=? id (lv-any-id lv))
                    value
                    e)]
               [lv-cons (f r) 
                (lv-cons (inner f)
                     (inner r))])]
            [(cons? e)
             (cons (inner (car e))
               (inner (cdr e)))]
            [else e]))])
    inner))
```

Code which heavily uses this function (multiple times, not just once) runs at 1800 ms for both versions. More interestingly, this version (my visualization of what was happening):

```
(define (substitute lv value)
  (local ([define inner
        (lambda (e)
          (cond [(LogicVar? e)
             (type-case LogicVar e
               [lv-any (id) (if (symbol=? id (lv-any-id lv))
                    value
                    e)]
               [lv-cons (f r) 
                (lv-cons ((substitute lv value) f)
                     ((substitute lv value) r))])]
            [(cons? e)
             (cons ((substitute lv value) (car e))
               ((substitute lv value) (cdr e)))]
            [else e]))])
    inner))
```

Runs at 2000 ms. So there is definitely a slow-down if the calls to substitute within substitute were each creating a lambda, but it appears this is not the case with the shortcut notation.

Comment: If you benchmark in DrScheme remember to turn debugging of
(in the language menu, choose "Details") - or try the timings in MzScheme.