# How does Racket handle (define (f (x y)) body)?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm learning Racket, and wrote this definition:

```
(define y 2)
(define (f (x y))
  (print x)
  (print y))
```

When I evaluate `(f 1)`, `x` is bound to `1`, and `y` is bound to `2`.  This seems very strange to me.  How is this expression being expanded? What does the interpreter do with this?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Oops, I'm using a Racket interpreter, and such scenario really happens.

Comment: The Racket application supports a lot of languages. Which language are you using that supports such syntax?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but definitely related: [Implementation of Curried Functions in Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/q/357353/1281433).  It asks about things like `(define ((func x) y) …)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It's an optional argument

The grammar for definitions in Racket is in the documentation.

> #### [3.14 Definitions: define, define-syntax, ...](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html)
>
> ```
> (define id expr)
> (define (head args) body ...+)
>
> head  =       id
>       |       (head args)
>
> args  =       arg ...
>       |       arg ... . rest-id
>
> arg   =       arg-id
>       |       [arg-id default-expr]
>       |       keyword arg-id
>       |       keyword [arg-id default-expr]
> ```

Most of my Lisping is in Common Lisp where square brackets aren't parentheses, so I initially misread the grammar. The part about `[arg-id default-expr]` means you can have an optional argument with a default value.  So

```
(define (f (x y)) …)
```

defines `f` as a procedure that accepts 0 or 1 arguments.  If the argument is not provided, then its default value is `y`.  That's why this works when you have an earlier definition of `y`.  This also means that you can call `(f)`, and you should see the value of `y` printed:

[image]

This was pointed out to me on the Racket users mailing list by Robby Findler and Tony Garnock-Jones in the thread [[racket] (define (f (x y)) body) when y has a previous definition](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2014-June/063069.html).

### It's not legal in R5RS

This isn't legal in R<sup>5</sup>RS Scheme.  The definition for definitions is given in:

> #### [5.2  Definitions](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-8.html#%_sec_5.2)
>
> Definitions are valid in some, but not all, contexts where expressions
>   are allowed. They are valid only at the top level of a  and
>   at the beginning of a .
>
> A definition should have one of the following forms:
>
> ```
> (define <variable> <expression>)
> (define (<variable> <formals>) <body>)
> ```
>
> should be either a sequence of zero or more variables, or a
>   sequence of one or more variables followed by a space-delimited period
>   and another variable (as in a lambda expression). This form is
>   equivalent to
>
> ```
> (define <variable>
>   (lambda (<formals>) <body>)).
>
> (define (<variable> . <formal>) <body>)
> ```
>
> should be a single variable. This form is equivalent to
>
> ```
> (define <variable>
>   (lambda <formal> <body>)).
> ```

Dr.Racket won't accept your definition in the R5RS language:

[image: Dr.Racket Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for reminding, I really appreciate your patient.

Comment: You are right. Sorry for my mistake, I afraid I typed too much in my environment, and `y` maybe has defined somewhere...

Comment: well, if `y` is a procedure, try calling `(y)` and find out what it is. :)

Comment: If I define `y` first, this question still bother me: `(define y 1) (define (f (x y)) (print x) (print y))`, `(f 1)` will working. Is it related to Racket? Since it is not in R5RS standard.

Comment: Saying that `(f 1)` is still working doesn't mean all that much on its own.  What does it do?

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it, and yeah, that's strange. I don't know why that works. I think it's probably a good thing to ask the Racket developers, so I sent a message to the users mailing list.

Comment: Oh, I misread the grammar.  It's an optional argument, and I've updated my answer.

Comment: @kedebug Does the updated answer explain this more clearly now?

Comment: I think this is a great example of where the Racket convention of using square brackets in certain cases -- such as default arguments -- is helpful. At a glance, it's more obvious what's going on. Well, except when it's not. i.e. If you're accustomed to that convention and expect it, but someone doesn't follow it, it can be confusing -- like it was at first to Joshua and to me, too!

Comment: @GregHendershott Well, if it had been used in the *code*, it probably have would have been more obvious.  In the documentation, though, it's more confusing, because `[ ]` is often used in grammars to denote optional things.  E.g., take a look at Common Lisp's grammar for lambda lists in [3.4.1 Ordinary Lambda Lists](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_da.htm)

Answer (score 3):

In Racket an argument can be defined as `(argument-name default-value)` (usually you'd use square brackets for this, but that's only a matter of style - the language itself does not care).

So `(define (f (x y)) ...)` defines a function `f` that takes one argument named `x` whose default value is `y`.